# Saxonica 9.7 HE in C#

Tags: c#, api, saxon

I'm trying to get Saxon 9.7 HE up and running in C#, and failing miserably.

As per instructions, I am downloading and running https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.7/SaxonHE9-7-0-14N-setup.exe/download

This installs a bunch of files into C:\Program Files\Saxonica\SaxonHE9.7N.

In the bin folder inside this one, the following files are present:

[image]

No matter which DLLs I add as references to my project, the "using Saxon.Api;" reference fails to resolve.

Am I using the correct DLLs here? Is it some sort of .Net version mismatch? My class library project is set to .Net 3.5 currently.

Thanks for any help

Comment: saxon9he-api.dll contains the `Saxon.Api` namespace. It's a .NET 4.0 dll; you'll need to use at least .NET 4.0 for your project.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the case, it's in contradiction to the information supplied on their own site http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!about/installationdotnet

"To run Saxon you need to install the .NET platform, version 3.5 or later."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum supported version of .NET for Saxon is indeed 4.0.

The bug is in the documentation which will be updated shortly: See bug issue: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3085

Thanks for reporting the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Do any of the previous versions support lower versions of .Net? I can try them all sequentially, but you might save me some time if you happen to know offhand.

Comment: I think you would have to go as far back as to the Saxon 9.5 release

Comment: 9.5 works, thanks (requirement for .Net 3.5 comes from BizTalk 2009, for reference)

Answer (score 1):

Some guess work here. But the dependency on .net 4 is most likley from the compiling of the C# wrapper over the saxon java library that was converted using IKVM. IKVM says it only requires .net 2.0, so I think the only place that dependancy can come from is the saxon9he-api.

You should be able to build this yourself, its quite thin.
https://dev.saxonica.com/repos/archive/opensource/latest9.7/hen/csource/api/Saxon.Api/

Otherwise if its a show stopper ask Michael Kay (the author), he's pretty active on stack overflow.

**Updated**

I was curious so I checked, the .Net 4 dependency seems to come from the saxon9he-api (which i'm fairly certain could be re-compiled under 3.5 with no/minimal changes), the same for the Query and Transform exe's.

[image]